# unable to send email on my Exim-Dovecot-Afterlogic webmail setup

Tags: email, amazon-ec2, ubuntu-12.04, exim, dovecot

I am working on ec2 ubuntu 12.04 hvm client. I have setup an MTA i-e Exim and IMAP/POP Server i-e dovecot and a webmail client afterlogic. IMAP server is working well but SMTP gives error. While sending email afterlogic fails. I have checked logs and got connection fails connecting to 127.0.0.1:25. In Exim configuration file I have uncommented the line which gives list of ports including 25:487:etc
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution to this !!!
Open /usr/exim/configure in your favorite editor and change the following lines:

In MAIN CONFIGURATION section 
change local_interfaces = <;127.0.0.1; to local_interfaces = <; your-ec2-privateIP ;
change sender_unqualified_hosts = localhost to sender_unqualified_hosts = your-ec2-privateIP
change recipient_unqualified_hosts = localhost to recipient_unqualified_hosts = your-ec2-privateIP

restart exim and port 25 smtp will be open and you will be able to send email